# android-menudrawer with a header and a content

Tags: android, layout, slidingmenu

I'm using [Android-menudrawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer) of simonvt ...

in my project we need a top menu that starts directly below a header ....

Now I was able to obtain this structure:

- -> (ActionBar)
- -> (MenuDrawer)
- -> (Content)

Except that I would not use an ActionBar ... since I need to use a layout for the header with a background and actions mapped with hotspots ... like this for example ... :

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/

Is there a way to use the menudrawer in an activity composed like this:

- -> (Header)
- -> (MenuDrawer)
- -> (Content)

?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the menudrawer via xml, there's even a [sample](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/blob/master/samples/res/layout/activity_layoutsample.xml) for that. Then you just create a layout that has a header above the drawer.

Comment: Yes, correct, I tried but unfortunately it seems that there is a problem with layout. Also do not understand why I can not use android: layout_width and android: layout_height = wrap_content in a parent linear layout perhaps it is not right to use the linear layout? ... thanks ...

Comment: Page no found in that link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use this library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

With this you can use slidingmenu without SherlockactionBar.

To create a header, you can use https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

With this you can create a custom header and merge with the content.